# how to post parameter binding using [frombody] in nodejs or angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ccavenue

I won't hit ccavenue request formbody in my application which we use nodejs angularjs

```
window.location.url(formbody)
```

"formBody": "https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction\"/> document.redirect.submit();"

REQUIRED TO HIT CCAVENUE TEST URL

Answer (score 0):

var formElem = angular.element(response.formBody);// formBody is response of ccavenue 
                    formElem.append('');//response.data.encoded is encoded data form ccavRequestHandler
                    formElem.append('');//response.data.accessCode is accesscode form ccavRequestHandler

```
                console.log('formElem: ', formElem[0]); 
                angular.element('body').append(formElem); // inserts specified content at the end of the selected elements
                formElem.submit(); final submit
```